# Realtime outgoing voice modification on android during call

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I am research assistant for an android app. The app is about real-time outgoing voice modification on android devices. For example one of its use could be that when there is an incoming call from an unknown number, the user, in order not to be recognized, will have the option to answer the call in a modified voice. The modification of voice has to take place in real time during the call.

The question is, *is it possible to intercept the outgoing voice stream and modify it in real-time?* If so what APIs are available?

My research shows that it is possible to get a handle of the outgoing voice, but it is not clear whether it can only be used for recording purposes or it can also be used to modify the outgoing voice?

There is at least one such application which appears to do what I am talking about. http://www.prweb.com/releases/voice/scrambler/prweb10987365.htm

If it has been done by someone there must be a way to do it then!

Comment: While the recording might be possible, you can't inject the audio into the call. You might be able to do it at the audioflinger or rild layer but it would be different per device and not at all official or reliable.

Comment: You can of course put the calk on speakerphone and play something from the speaker and it would be picked up by the mic. But it's nowhere near the tight realtime loop you're looking for. Also, you don't only need to inject audio but also block the plain audio stream from reaching the modem...